# Customize an icon for a USB stick on Mac and automount a dmg file

Tags: macos, icons, usb-storage, osx-leopard

I want to make a custom icon to a usb stick on mac and show that instead of the ugly blank icon that exists by default

As I have to compile a presentation I want the users to be able to quick access a .html file that I have on the root of the stick.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this seems like a [su] question.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the image you onto the clipboard, select the item (USB Drive), File > Get Info, select icon and paste the content of the clipboard.

Edit: As for automounting, the system is already auto-mounting the USB stick you're plugging in, so I guess I don't understand that part of the question.